# why isn't the input text file being read into the ArrayList<String>, diary?

Tags: java

Here's my code:

```
public void readFile() throws IOException {
    System.out.println("Input file name: ");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String readName = in.nextLine();
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(new File(readName));
    System.out.println("Reading file...");
    while (reader.hasNextLine()) {
        System.out.println(reader.nextLine());
    }
    System.out.println("File read.");
    Scanner inAgain = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Would you like to read this into the current Diary?");
    System.out.println("Warning: This will overwrite your current Diary!");
    String readFileConfirm = inAgain.nextLine();
    ArrayList<String> readData = new ArrayList<String>();
    if (readFileConfirm.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
        for (int i = 0; i < readData.size(); i++) {
            readData.add(reader.nextLine());
        }
        System.out.println("Data added to extra array...");
        System.out.println("Here are the contents.");
        for (int i = 0; i < readData.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(readData.get(i));
        }
        System.out.println("Contents read.");
        System.out.println("Now overwriting current Diary with read file...");
        diary.clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < diary.size(); i++) {
            diary.add(readData.get(i));
        }
        System.out.println("New Diary created!");
        System.out.println("Use 'recall' to see your new Diary!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Very well, returning to first command entry.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at:

```
ArrayList<String> readData = new ArrayList<String>();
if (readFileConfirm.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
    for (int i = 0; i < readData.size(); i++) {
        readData.add(reader.nextLine());
    }
```

You're calling `readLine` while `i < readData`, but `readData` starts empty so the loop never runs.  Your loop should be based on the input, not the empty and resizable ArrayList.  Look at [`Scanner.hasNextLine`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextLine%28%29).

You have a similar issue later:

```
diary.clear();
for (int i = 0; i < diary.size(); i++) {
    diary.add(readData.get(i));
}
```

`diary.size()` starts at zero, so the loop will never run.  Also, if `diary` is an ArrayList, it looks like you can just do:

```
diary = readData;
```

If it's another [`Collection`](http://java.sun.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html), you can do:

```
diary.clear()
diary.addAll(readData);
```

That will simply add all the elements in `readData` to `diary`.